# Elastic beanstalk - unable to pip install some requirements

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to run a django app on elastic beanstalk. When I run `eb create django-env` it's stated in the logs that some requirements can't be installed:

```
2020/06/17 12:08:38.841799 [ERROR] Creating a Pipfile for this projectâ€¦
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfileâ€¦
An error occurred while installing mkl-random==1.1.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing mkl-service==2.3.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing openapi-client==1.0.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pandas==0.23.4! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pypiwin32==223! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pywin32==228! Will try again.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 862, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, False, failed_deps_queue, retry=False)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: []
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-random==1.1.1 (from versions: none)', 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-random==1.1.1']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...

2020/06/17 12:08:38.845458 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c python3 -m pipenv install -r requirements.txt --skip-lock failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Creating a Pipfile for this projectâ€¦
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfileâ€¦
An error occurred while installing mkl-random==1.1.1! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing mkl-service==2.3.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing openapi-client==1.0.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pandas==0.23.4! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pypiwin32==223! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pywin32==228! Will try again.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 862, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, False, failed_deps_queue, retry=False)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: []
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-random==1.1.1 (from versions: none)', 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-random==1.1.1']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

How should I circumvent this?

Comment: Where did you see a version `1.1.1` of `mkl-random`? The latest version on pypi is `1.0.1.1`.

Comment: I've seen these errors happen when the version of Python you're deploying is different than the version you've been using for your local development. Ensure that the version of your eb environment is the same as your local dev environment, as some versions of the libraries you're using may not be compatible with an older version of Python.